# Pythonic way to break out of loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

Total python beginner here.

I have the following function, which checks if a string derived from certain inputs exists in a text file. It loops through each line of the text file, to see if an exact match is found.

I have to break out of looping, immediately after the match is found, to avoid needless looping.

Here is the code:

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date,ZoneCity):    #   function to check if a given DateZoneCity
                                                                    #   combination had already been completely downloaded
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0] + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    with open(Record_File) as download_status:
        DateZoneCity_exists = False
        for line in download_status:
            if string_to_match in line:
                DateZoneCity_exists = True                      #   if match found, then set "DateZoneCity_exists" to True
                break                                           #   and break out from the [for line in download_status:] loop
        if DateZoneCity_exists: return True
    download_status.close()
```

I am searching for a more concise, pythonic way to structure the code. Is there anything I can do to make this better? Somehow to eliminate the need for "DateZoneCity_exists" and the second If statement?

Comment: This belongs to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm sorry, should I be doing something? Am I supposed to move the thread, I dunno how to though.

Comment: @Chinmay Here are a few posts you may want to consider: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260427/4428725)

Comment: What is the `download_status.closed` doing at the end?

Comment: @200_success, thank you. I changed it to download_status.close() . Had copied an online example wrongly :P

Comment: Your online example is wrong. `download_status` will be automatically closed when leaving the `with` block — that's the point of using the `with` block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feels like a situation where `any` would be the best solution:

```
# Function to check if a given DateZoneCity
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date, ZoneCity):
    # Combination had already been completely downloaded
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0]
                                                      + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    with open(Record_File) as download_status:
        return any((string_to_match in line) for line in download_status)
```

Note that in this case it will return `False` on negative rather than your current implementation that will return `None`, also note that it does break out of the looping immediately upon finding a positive result so it does not require looping through the entire file either way.

Comment: Nice. Very concise, Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just `return` instead of `break`:

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date,ZoneCity):
    """Check if a given DataZoneCity combination had already been downloaded."""
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0] + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    with open(Record_File) as download_status:
        for line in download_status:
            if string_to_match in line:
                return True
    return False  # No match found.
```

Comment: Oh, so as I understand, the return statement will also immediately do the job of breaking out, avoiding future loops, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how big your text file is, you can read it into a string, and just use that (easier and often faster than reading and checking line per line):

```
if string_to_match in open(Record_File).read():
    return True
```

In your example:

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date,ZoneCity):                   
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0] + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    if string_to_match in open(Record_File).read():
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put a for loop here, See the updated code.

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date,ZoneCity):
    """Check if a given DataZoneCity combination had already been downloaded."""
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0] + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    with open(Record_File) as download_status:
        if string_to_match in download_status.read():
            return True
    return False  # No match found.
```

Comment: I was concerned that without the for loop, the whole file would be loaded and it would take a lot of RAM. No?

Comment: Yeah, but if its a small file. there is no need to add a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If record_file is small then you can use `in` directly with `if`statement like:-

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date,ZoneCity):                   
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0] + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    if string_to_match in open(Record_File).read():
        return True
```

while if record_file is large then you have to iterate through each line for finding a match like:-

```
def DateZoneCity_downloaded_previously(Order_Date, ZoneCity):
    string_to_match = Order_Date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + "-" + ZoneCity[0]  + "-" + ZoneCity[1]
    with open(Record_File) as download_status:
        return is_empty((string_to_match in line) for line in download_status)
```

because reading line by line will save storage memory used for saving line.